# Delphi Apache-Module with SSO

Tags: apache, delphi, single-sign-on, kerberos

we successfully created an apache module with Embarcadero Delphi (10.3). Next step is the idea to extend this module with SSO-functionality (NTML/Kerberos).
I understand there are several modules for apache to enable the sso-features for php/html-content and directories by extending the httpd.conf-file (or even locations like those the module uses).
But i have no idea how to access the apache-server-variables or the information about the sso-credentials (windows logon-name) from inside my apache-module.

Perhaps someone can give me a hint here.

Possible alternatives:

- Recode the negotiate-handshakes (ntml/krb) inside the module (already did this for indy)
- Use a little php-script file to access the variables (with
  redirect/ajax for example)
- Somehow (would not know how) add those information to the request-headers inside apache before going into the module (sounds insecure)

But i would like to use an easier way ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the xxm project (which also has an Apache httpd module!) I've [implemented NTLM authentication](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/http/xxmHttpCtx.pas#L408) using the [AcquireCredentialsHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acquirecredentialshandlea) and [AcceptSecurityContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acceptsecuritycontext) calls.

It works using the `WWW-Authenticate` request and response values. First there's `NTLM`, followed by one or more round-trips with `NTLM` followed by a space and base64 encoded data you need to pass until you get a `SEC_E_OK` value back.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i already did this for indy (including ntml and kerberos). But as apache already has those modules i hoped there was an easier way.